# How to know if a specific file is being ignored or not

Tags: svn, svnignore

I would like to know if there is any way to know if an specific file is being ignored or not inside a subversioned project. Is there any command for that?

Answer (score 2):

`svn status --no-ignore` and then look for files with status `I`

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re26.html

Comment: SVNBook 1.0? It's better to reference the actual one: SVNBook 1.7 http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html

Comment: Sure, but having it in the 1.0 book means it's going to work even if you have a pretty old version installed :)

Comment: noting in the answer body that the feature was available since ver 1.0 would be enough, IMHO.